# Package to align similar (parts of) algorithms for easier comparison

Tags: algorithm2e

I have two similar algorithms that I'd like to present side-by-side and I'd like to align similar parts of the code. At present I'm using:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \eIf{$i = 0$}{
        $a\leftarrow b$\;
        \If{$j \not= 0$}{
            $x\leftarrow f(i,j)$\;
        }
    }{
        $a\leftarrow c$\;
    }
    ...
\end{algorithm}

\columnbreak

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \If{$i = 0 \wedge j \not= 0$}{
        \vskip 2em
        $x\leftarrow f(i,j)$\;
    }
    \vskip 1em
    $a\leftarrow c$\;
    ...
\end{algorithm}
\end{multicols}
```

This somewhat succeeds in aligning the `if`-statement, `x <- f(i,j)`, and `a <- c`, but the alignment isn't quite right, because my vskips aren't using the right lengths. This can probably be resolved, but nonetheless: *This is clearly a hack*. Which leads to my question:

**Is there a better way (perhaps using a package) to present two algorithms side-by-side such that certain parts of the algorithms are aligned?**

Comment: The proper `\vskip` is `\vskip<n>\baselineskip` where `<n>` is an integer.  Then it all lines up.

Comment: E.g.: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e,multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \eIf{$i = 0$}{
        $a\leftarrow b$\;
        \If{$j \not= 0$}{
            $x\leftarrow f(i,j)$\;
        }
    }{
        $a\leftarrow c$\;
    }
    ...
\end{algorithm}
\columnbreak
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \If{$i = 0 \wedge j \not= 0$}{
        \vskip 2\baselineskip
        $x\leftarrow f(i,j)$\;
    }
    \vskip \baselineskip
    $a\leftarrow c$\;
    \vskip \baselineskip
    ...
\end{algorithm}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes that almost lines up, but not quite. (Note that the vertical space isn't just line space, additional spacing is being introduced too.) In any case, it still remains a hack, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: My compilation lines up exactly (though I am not sure what exactly you mean by "additional space");  However, I did not post as an answer precisely because you seemed to want something other than manually counting `\vskips`.

Comment: My mistake: Yours does line-up, but it doesn't line-up using `\usepackage[vlined,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}`, which is possibly what introduces "additional spaces." Anyhow, this probably isn't worth fixing, because as you mention, I want to avoid manually counting \vskips.

Comment: Interesting question - but how would the alignment of non-identical statements (such as the `If` and `eIf` in the example) need to be implemented? With some kind of similarity measure, or with manual hints?

Comment: @Marijn I'd expect alignment issues to be dealt with using manual hints. (I'm also interested in automated highlighting of distinctions, but that can be handled manually with relative ease.)